# EF 4.1 Linq Predicate Contains Generates desired SQL when using hard-coded string but not with string variable

Tags: entity-framework

I have this code:

```
string name ="M";
Expression<Func<Organization, bool>> getExpression1 = r => r.Name.Contains(name);
Expression<Func<Organization, bool>> getExpression2 = r => r.Name.Contains("M");

GetOrgListBy(getExpression); 
GetOrgListBy(getExpression2); 

public IEnumerable<Organization> GetOrgListBy(Expression<Func<Organization, bool>>   filter)
{
  return DataContext.Parties.OfType<Organization>().Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

Question:
I am passing a simple expression to a repository function
that gets `List<Organization>` by matching the name passed.
When I view the sql trace for `getExpression1` (uses a string variable), the expression  generates a `[Name] like plinq_variable` sql statement
which omits the `%` operator. My intention is to generate a 
`[Name] like '%' + plinq_variable + '%'` sql statement

However, when I when using `getExpression2` (hard-coded the string), the expression successfully
generates a `[Name] like N'%M%'` sql statement.

Why doesn't `getExpression1` generate the `%` operator?
How can I make it generate a `%` operator in the sql just like `getExpression2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first expression translates into a parametrized SQL query. The variable in the Where clause ...

```
[Name] like plinq_variable
```

... is set to the value

```
@plinq_variable=N'%M%'
```

when the query is executed. The second expression translates to a SQL query with a hardcoded string literal:

```
[Name] like N'%M%'
```

Then this query is directly executed.

The result for both expressions and queries is the same.

Comment: Ok my mistake was that I was checking the sql before .ToList() method but the expression actually does append the % operator. Once ToList() executes, I just couldn't view that sql. I should check the trace on sql server instead of using object query trace to string to get a more accurate picture